# how to ng serve custom env in angular6

Tags: angular

Per the readme of angular 6:

```
## Development server

Run `ng serve` for a dev server. Navigate to `http://localhost:4200/`. The app will automatically reload if you change any of the source files.
```

Before 6 for my local env I would run the below:

```
  ng serve --env=local
```

Well not anymore......

In angular.json I added the below:

```
 "configurations": {
      "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
```

So how to I serve my local env?

I tried the below:

```
ng serve --configuration=local
Configuration 'local' could not be found in project
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you added your `local` configuration under the `build` section of the *angular.json*, you will also need to add one in the `serve` section.

Something like this:

```
"serve": {
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "programName:build:production"
    },
    "local": {
      "browserTarget": "programName:build:local"
    }
  }
```

Then you can serve the application like so:

```
ng s -c=local
```

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like this. Although when I set this up, it seems to build the entire project after small changes in the Angular project. Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "serverbin-angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "browserTarget": "projectname-angular:build:production"
            },
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "serverbin-angular:build:dev"
            },
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "serverbin-angular:build:local"
            }
          }
        }
```